# What SFTP client with HTTP proxy support to use on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, sftp, private-key

I am looking for an SFTP client for Mac which supports private keys and also ***HTTP*** proxies.

Transmit or Cyberduck don't support HTTP proxies.

*Please don't say FileZilla, it looks ugly and I'd rather fly to the datacenter and deliver the files myself.*

Comment: Why not [use corkscrew to get through the HTTP proxy](http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php)?

Comment: I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Get a 3G card and circumvent the corporate proxy? I'm afraid you're out of options, using corkscrew could at least give a new nice SFTP client GUI...